# Fixing the Font Issue in Venn Diagrams with Tikz Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am novice when it comes to Tikz. I have three Venn Diagrams. Fore some reason
the text inside the Venn diagrams start at the lower half of the node. Is there a way to automatically align/fit it to the size of the shape?

```
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2.1cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(55:3.5cm) circle (2.1cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:3.5cm) circle (2.1cm)}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,on grid,auto] 
\begin{scope}[shift={(4cm,-15cm)}, fill opacity=0.5]
        \fill[gray!30!white] \firstcircle;
        \fill[blue!30!white] \secondcircle;
        \fill[cyan!60!white] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{Economic Layer}: \\
        A\\
        B\\
        C\\
        D
        \end{tabular}
        };
        \draw \secondcircle node [above,text width=2cm,align=center] {
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         \textbf{Technology Layer}\\
         A \& B\\
         C \& D
         \end{tabular}
         };
        \draw \thirdcircle node [below,text width=2cm,align=center] {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{Social  Layer}\\
        A\\
        B\\
        C
        \end{tabular}
        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Sorry if you find this discouraging, but I can't remember ever learning anything of any value from a Venn diagram. I suspect they are never really helpful. I think the reason is that in practice it is clear whether various sets of objects have a common overlap. I would like to see a useful example of a Venn diagram, exposing some counterintuitive structure in some intuitively well understood sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the text in the centre then you can add the `text centered` option to the tikz picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2.1cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(55:3.5cm) circle (2.1cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:3.5cm) circle (2.1cm)}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,on grid,auto, text centered] 
\begin{scope}[shift={(4cm,-15cm)}, fill opacity=0.5]
        \fill[gray!30!white] \firstcircle;
        \fill[blue!30!white] \secondcircle;
        \fill[cyan!60!white] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[] {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{Economic Layer}: \\
        A\\
        B\\
        C\\
        D
        \end{tabular}
        };
        \draw \secondcircle node [] {
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         \textbf{Technology Layer}\\
         A \& B\\
         C \& D
         \end{tabular}
         };
        \draw \thirdcircle node [] {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{Social  Layer}\\
        A\\
        B\\
        C
        \end{tabular}
        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

By my eye there is still a problem with this though as the bottom left circle labeled "economic layer" overlaps slightly. To fix this manually you could use the `xshift` and `yshift`options for each node to fine tune the positioning.

Comment: magic touch, works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you still don't know, but `nodes` can have different shapes. The basic ones are rectangular and circular but you can find come more in `shapes` tikzlibrary.

In your code, circles and text are different entities and you have to adjust them. Another solution could be to use circular nodes:

```
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=4.2cm, fill=gray!30, align=center, opacity=0.5, text opacity=1] 
    {\\
    \textbf{Economic Layer}: \\
    A\\
    B\\
    C\\
    D
    };
```

This command draws a circle with minimum radius=2.1cm (if inner text needs more space, the node will grow) and text aligned to center. By declaring `align` option, there's no need to include `tabulars` inside the node but `\\` is still valid as newline command.

Instead of repeating all these options in every node, you can declare a `.style`:

```
mycircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=4.2cm, align=center, 
                  fill=#1, opacity=0.5, text opacity=1}
```

This style has one parameter (`#1`) which corresponds to filling color.

Your code could be written like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=4.2cm, align=center, 
                    fill=#1, opacity=0.5, text opacity=1}] 
        \node[mycircle=gray!30] {\\
        \textbf{Economic Layer}: \\
        A\\
        B\\
        C\\
        D
        };
        \node[mycircle=blue!30] at (60:3.5cm) {
         \textbf{Technology Layer}\\
         A \& B\\
         C \& D
         };
        \node[mycircle=cyan!60] at (0:3.5cm) {
        \textbf{Social  Layer}\\
        A\\
        B\\
        C
        };
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]